# Contents of the OSX Documents folder appears empty from an ethernet-connected Linux machine

Tags: network, time-machine, migration

I have recently migrated a 2012 MacBookPro via Time Machine and Migration Assist to a new MBP running Monterey 12.2. The new Mac is connected via a Gb ethernet cable to a Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04) in exactly the same way as the old Mac. I have always been able to swap text files/graphics etc between shared Documents folders on the two computers, but now, when I log-on remotely to the Mac from my Linux machine, the Mac Documents folder appears empty. What puzzles me is that I can see the entire Mac hard drive from my Linux machine - just not the contents of the Documents folder...
The new Mac is able to connect to the Linux machine without issues. Apple Support recommended that I erase and re-install Linux on the other machine, but I'm not sure if I should take that seriously. Has anyone ever encountered something similar, and if so, do you know if there's a way to 'see' Documents again?

Comment: Most likely a permission issue. How do you log in from your Linux box?

Comment: Your Documents folder is protected.  I doubt that it's going to be visible over the network.

Comment: The Linux Box runs Ubuntu 20.04LTS. To connect to my Mac I use Files > Network > MyComputer(remote login). I enter username and password and then I can see the whole system, including hidden files folders etcetc. I can open, edit and save anything eg ~Users/.Rhistory and copy to /usr/local/bin, but nothing visible in Documents. This just wasn't an issue on my old machine running Catalina. Incidentally, my old Mac encounters exactly the same issue trying to connect. I can copy files from Linux to OSX, but then they disappear from 'Linux view' after reboot :(

Comment: Repeating it doesn't change the answer.  It's still a protected folder.

Answer (score 4):

Well thanks Marc :)

Solution:
Following a suggestion here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250716547 I did the following:

1. De-selected all services/users/groups etc from Sharing.
2. Rebooted the computer and re-selected screen sharing, file sharing and remote login.
3. Rebooted the networked computer.

The contents of Documents are now visible from the networked machine and open to scp and rsync file transfers.

Caveat!
Using Files (=Finder in Ubuntu) to copy files to OSX loses date/timestamps. These are preserved, though, using scp or rsync.

Comment: Well spotted: if it is not a permissions issue, it is probably a cache one :)

Comment: I had the same issue accessing the documents folder between two Macs. Disabling + enabling file sharing did help. No need to reboot one of both machines.